# psych and Hmisc packages with describe class

Tags: r, dataframe, psych, hmisc, describe

I am on Mac OS 10.10 with R 3.1.1

I have the following dataframe `x` which I am trying to get its descriptive statistics using `describe` from `psych` package (note that I `Hmisc` package  which has the same `describe` function is detached for now)

```
set.seed(10)
x<-data.frame(a=seq(1:10),b=rnorm(10), c=rnorm(10))
x_des<-psych::describe(x)
x_des<-x_des[,-c(3,4,5)]
```

this code gives me the object `x_dex` which has a `data.frame` class.

If I load `Hmisc` package, the class of the object `x_dex` changes to `describe` if I used the same code like above.

Since I want the object to have a `data.frame` class to be able to write it into excel file, I have tried to use:

```
data.frame(x_des)
```

but it give the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""describe"" to a data.frame
```

Need to know why this happen when loading `Hmisc` package and any proper solution.

Comment: should use `as.data.frame`. and I assumed that `x_des(, -c(3,4,5))` is a typo because that is a syntax error. since `class(x_des)` is data.frame and describe, `as.data.frame` looks for a method for "descibe", doesn't find it, and you get an error. You can force `as.data.frame` to use the data frame method on x_des by `as.data.frame.data.frame(x_des)` and I get the expected result

Comment: @rawr I fixed the error in `x_des(, -c(3,4,5))`. I did use `as.data.frame.data.frame(x_des)` and it gave me the following error `Error in if (i > 1L) class(x) <- cl[-(1L:(i - 1L))] : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: the S3 methods for describe objects from the Hmisc and psych package are conflicting. you could strip the classes from `x_des` as in `class(x_des) <- 'data.frame'` I'm not sure what the psych authors intended for the describe class--there don't seem to be any S3 methods for it. Hmisc, on the other hand, has a few methods. I think you could get away with changing the class unless you are using it down the line for some reason

Comment: As the author of psych, I will add that the describe class is used in the print psych function.  Perhaps mistakenly, but routinely, I class the output of most psych functions as class(result) <- c("psych", "funtionname").  I do this to simplify the appropriate print and summary functions.

Comment: @rawr I ended up striping the class like you mentioned. Still thinking to limit my usage of Hmisc as an alternative.